# XMLHttpRequest prevents my curve from being displayed in script

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I try to receive data in real time to display on a curve but when I use XMLHttpRequest, my curve no longer appears

here are my codes :

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    include("connexion.php");
 ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <!-- CSS only -->

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="link_wrapper">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("link_wrapper").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "server.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
setInterval(function(){
    loadXMLDoc();
    // 1sec
},1000);

window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
</script>
```

I receive the real time data thanks to ajax jquery but I can not afffier my curve

I use lq library canavasjs to display the curve when I did not integrate ajax inside, my code displayed the curve without worries, so I say to myself auie c is possible aue that is a ajax

**server.php**

```
<?php

include('connexion.php');
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT valeur from tension ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $tension = $row['valeur'];
        echo $tension;
    }
echo "sortir";  
$dataPoints = array();
$y = $tension;


for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  $y = $y; 
  array_push($dataPoints, array("x" => $i, "y" => $y));
}
 echo "\naubout";
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
window.onload = function() {
 
var dataPoints = <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  theme: "light2",
  title: {
    text: "Valeur detension en temps reel"
  },
  axisX:{
    title: "Time in millisecond"
  },
  axisY:{
    suffix: " V"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0#",
    toolTipContent: "{y} V",
    dataPoints: dataPoints
  }]
});
chart.render();
 
var updateInterval = 1500;
setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, updateInterval);
 
var xValue = dataPoints.length;
var yValue = dataPoints[dataPoints.length - 1].y;
 
function updateChart() {
  yValue += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1;
  dataPoints.push({ x: xValue, y: yValue });
  xValue++;
  chart.render();
};
 
}
</script>
  
</head>
<body>
  

</body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

**connexion.php**

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username  = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "iot";



    $db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$db) {
        die("Connection Failed". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: have you checked that your ajax call actually returns what you think, what is the content of `this.responseText`

Comment: thank you I don't know because it's my first time to use ajax, the goal being to receive real-time data from my database. But I think it only returns the texts, however when I try to display a text in server.php inside the script tag it does not display

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to consider using `.load()`. Also remember that `<script>` tags are often not used or loaded with AJAX requested HTML data. I would advise updating your PHP to gather and collect the data and present it as JSON or XML (instead of HTML). This way, your JavaScript can call up the Data from the server and perform the needed operations to display it.

Comment: Thank you yes I will try load (), to better understand my situation the script tags are not taken into account during an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Create a PHP, something like **getDataPoints.php**:

```
<?php
include('connexion.php');
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT valeur from tension ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$dataPoints = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  $y = $row['valeur'];
}
for($x; $x < 10; $x++){
  array_push($dataPoints, array($x, $y);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($dataPoints);
?>
```

Now when you call up *getDataPoints.php*, you should see JSON results (e.g. `$y` = `1`):

```
[
  [0, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [2, 1],
  [3, 1],
  [4, 1],
  [5, 1],
  [6, 1],
  [7, 1],
  [8, 1],
  [9, 1]
];
```

Now you can do things like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
var dataPoints, chart;

$.getJSON("getDataPoints.php", function(results){
  dataPoints = results;
  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      text: "Valeur detension en temps reel"
    },
    axisX:{
      title: "Time in millisecond"
    },
    axisY:{
      suffix: " V"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      yValueFormatString: "#,##0.0#",
      toolTipContent: "{y} V",
      dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
  });
  chart.render();
});
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="link_wrapper">
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you when I use your code nothing is displayed

Comment: @essayator You will want to test the PHP first. Make sure that requests to it are providing the correct response. Then you cna review your Client side code in the browser. Do you see errors in your Console. What does the Network tab look for the Request and the Response?

Comment: Thank you I receive the table from json but I cannot draw the curve,

Comment: I can not see send my code so that you can where I am because I manage to receive the values from the server, that is to say the table as you showed it to me but I cannot to draw the curve

Comment: @essayator as your example relies on server data, I can not really help much further. I am unable to replicate the issue or test further solutions without proper examples.

Comment: Yes, but we can admit that we are receiving data from the server as we did, but how are we treated to obtain the curve?

Comment: @essayator you should be able to pass them into `dataPoints` when initializing your Chart

Comment: Exactly that the problem I cannot transmit the data points during the initialization, I would like you to look at my code, it generates a problem at this level